# How to add a NIC in ubuntu 16.04.1 server?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I installed a new network card into my server. Since the naming differs from `ethX` to (something like) `enp3sX` i am a bit confused. Using `lspci -vv` i can see the new network card, but i cannot see the MAC address (in Capabilities) to put into a custom /etc/udev/rules.d/... file. BTW. the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-storage-custom.rules` file does not exist.

So how can i add this new network card into my system? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Do you get a MAC with `lshw -class network`? (under serial) And you should see the name with `cat /proc/net/dev` and create the corresponding config in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you wish to do, add a new virtual interface or rename an existing one. In any case, you and Zina are both using obsolete commands, please switch to using *iproute2* commands, for exactly the reason pointed out by Zina, *i.e.*, that some features (like detecting virtual interfaces) are not available to *ifconfig* and equally old utilities like *route*.

**Add a new virtual interface**. You do it as follows:

```
ip link add link usb0 myeth0 type macvlan
dhclient myeth0
ip addr show
```

where *usb0* is my ethernet device (if yours is called differently, please adjust accordingly). In a concrete case (**my** laptop) yields what follows:

```
# ip link add link usb0 myeth0 type macvlan
# dhclient -v myeth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/myeth0/be:6b:e7:1a:f6:50
Sending on   LPF/myeth0/be:6b:e7:1a:f6:50
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on myeth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x99d2cf3e)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.73.41 on myeth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3ecfd299)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.73.41 from 192.168.73.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.73.41 from 192.168.73.1
bound to 192.168.73.41 -- renewal in 19941 seconds.
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:eb:e8:2c:32:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.73.74/24 brd 192.168.73.255 scope global dynamic usb0
       valid_lft 38149sec preferred_lft 38149sec
    inet6 fe80::7470:2421:63cd:c4c1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:57:18:58:03:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.73.45/24 brd 192.168.73.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 1240sec preferred_lft 1240sec
    inet6 fe80::489e:3c3b:4b1b:6cb4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.1/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: myeth0@usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether be:6b:e7:1a:f6:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.73.41/24 brd 192.168.73.255 scope global myeth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bc6b:e7ff:fe1a:f650/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here, my ethernet card is called *usb0*, and I have added a new virtual interface onto it of the *macvlan* type. The command *ip addr show* displays also the interface MAC address (another possible command to identify the MAC address would be *ip link show*). The expression *myeth0@usb0* shows that this is a virtual interface built on the hardware of the *usb0* interface. Also, you may notice that the two interfaces have **distinct** MAC addresses, which makes it very easy to handle ARP traffic between the two.

**Rename your current interface**. You may do this with a udev rule, by creating the file */etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules* manually, which means that you do not have to worry about any *update* script overwriting it. Add to it the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="01:02:03:04:05:06", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

where you will have to change the MAC address to the one of your card.

**But**, if you are like me (*i.e.*, very impatient), then you may wish a more radical solution: I modified the following line in */etc/default/grub* to look as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

This will restore the naming conventions of yore (*eth0, usb0, wlan0*,...), which I found just good enough.

**EDIT**:

the answer to 7wp's question below (*how do I make this permanent*), depends on distro. In debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, MXLinux,...) you add to the ethernet stanza in */etc/network/interfaces*, assuming *eth0* to be the name of your ethernet NIC:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
       post-up ip link add link eth0 mynewNICname type macvlan
       post-up dhclient mynewNICname
       post-down dhclient -r mynewNICname
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to use the new iproute2 commands. The problem I have with your solution is that the OP said he added a new network card (I was the one mention vNIC as I tested on a virtualised server). Your answer is working if the usb0 device is already working (I assume). If you add an additional network card it will not be configured. I tried it your way (with a PCI plugged vNIC) and it did not work - it created a virtual adapter but I got no IP on it (even when I configured the underlying device) and those settings did not survive a reboot.

Comment: So I would be grateful if you could expand you answer. I assume it worked for you as you were using an USB NIC which might be discovered & configured differently then PCI devices. (had to put two comments as it was a bit too long).

Comment: @Zina The new network card is working already, since in the OP it is said it is detected by *lspci*. The fact that I used *usb0* is irrelevant, the commands above would have worked on an lspci card as well. If he cannot install the new card, then he would have had no driver for it, which is **not** stated in the question. You can get a virtual interface to persist thru reboots by adding the following stanza to */etc/network interfaces*: *auto myeth0 (newline) iface myeth0 inet dhcp (newline) pre-up ip link add link usb0 myeth0 type macvlan*, et voila.

Comment: @Zina As for this not working on a VM, I agree: in **any* Hypervisor, all interfaces need to be declared to the Hypervisor, one cannot add virtual interfaces from within the VM. But this was not what the OP was about, I think.

Comment: How do I make this permanent?  After rebooting I lose this new virtual network interface

Comment: @7wp See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

I have just tested this on a vSphere 6 VM with Ubuntu Server 16.04 installed:

- added an additional vNIC
- ifconfig showed only the first vNIC

  > ```
  > root@zinatest:~# ifconfig
  > ens160    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:02:53:53
  >           inet addr:10.140.253.53  Bcast:10.140.253.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  >           inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe02:5353/64 Scope:Link
  >           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  >           RX packets:1981 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  >           TX packets:997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  >           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  >           RX bytes:172503 (172.5 KB)  TX bytes:601251 (601.2 KB)
  >
  > lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
  >           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  >           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  >           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  >           RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  >           TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  >           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
  >           RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:100 (100.0 B)
  >
  > root@zinatest:~#
  > ```
- see name of added vNIC

  > ```
  > > root@zinatest:~# cat /proc/net/dev
  > Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
  >  face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  >     lo:   10216     136    0    0    0     0          0         0    10216     136    0    0    0     0       0          0
  > ens160:  119990    1406    0    0    0     0          0         0    40101     339    0    0    0     0       0          0
  > ens224:   76542    1068    0    0    0     0          0         0     1332      10    0    0    0     0       0          0
  > root@zinatest:~#
  > ```
- edit /etc/network/interface (added dhcp config for ens224

  > ```
  > root@zinatest:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
  > source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
  >
  > auto lo
  > iface lo inet loopback
  >
  > auto ens160
  > iface ens160 inet dhcp
  >
  > auto ens224
  > iface ens224 inet dhcp
  > root@zinatest:~#
  > ```
- restart network

  > `root@zinatest:~# service networking restart`
- and new vNIC working

  > ```
  >  root@zinatest:~# ifconfig
  >
  >  ens160    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:02:53:53
  >            inet addr:10.140.253.53  Bcast:10.140.253.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  >            inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe02:5353/64 Scope:Link
  >            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  >            RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  >            TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  >            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  >            RX bytes:4124 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:4002 (4.0 KB)
  >
  >  ens224    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:bd:a5:e2
  >            inet addr:10.140.253.127  Bcast:10.140.253.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  >            inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febd:a5e2/64 Scope:Link
  >            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  >            RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  >            TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  >            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  >            RX bytes:1370 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes:1192 (1.1 KB)
  >
  >  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
  >            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  >            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  >            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  >            RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  >            TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  >            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
  >            RX bytes:10216 (10.2 KB)  TX bytes:10216 (10.2 KB)
  >
  >  root@zinatest:~#
  > ```

**EDIT:**

[From ubuntu.help.com - Finding your network interface](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Finding_your_network_interface)

```
 ls /sys/class/net
 # or 
 ip addr
```

Where the `ls` output is the cleanest (not so messy as the `cat` output found above).